# IndentationError in Python list

Tags: python, indentation

Trying to write a python code to encrypt a string.

Encrypts the string and output is an encrypted string.

```
print "Enter the string "
a=raw_input()
e=''
i=0
while i<len(a):
  c=''
  c+=a[i]
  f=ord(c)
  if i%3==0:
    if f>21:
      e+=chr(f-21)
    else:
      e+=chr(f+5)
  elif i%3==1:
    if ord(c)>24:
      e+=chr(f-24)
    else:  
      e+=chr(f+2)   
  else:
    if ord(c)>21:
      e+=chr(f-20)
    else:
      e+=chr(f+6)     


  i=i+1
  del c

print e
```

But when on running this script, error comes.

```
e+=chr(f-24)
           ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: You may be mixing tabs with spaces.

Comment: It works for me. Take what you've got here and copy paste it back into your script.

Comment: You can remove `c` completely and write directly `f=ord(a[i])`

Comment: Use proper variable names! It is perhaps the most important thing in writing good code.

Comment: Use an IDE (I recommend PyCharm) and it will help greatly in keeping your code properly indented, as well as many other things.

Answer (score 0):

This indentation error is due to the mixing of tabs and spaces in your script. The fix is to go through each line in this file, making sure to use four spaces for each level of indentation. It looks like you are only using two spaces currently, so I'm not exactly sure how you've ended up in this position, but removing all indentation and using four spaces instead of tabs should resolve your problem.

Try to make your code look more like this and see if you still have these issues:

```
while i<len(a):
    c=''
    c+=a[i]
    f=ord(c)
    if i%3==0:
        if f>21:
```

Notice how there are four spaces instead of two for each level of indentation. This means the line `c=''` is four spaces to the right of the `while` statement. Additionally, the `if f>21` line is four spaces to the right of `if i%3==0`, and eight spaces to the right of the `while` statement, since it's two levels of indentation under the `while` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up your code:

```
plaintext = raw_input("Enter the string ")
encrypted = ''
for index, char in enumerate(plaintext):
    char_code = ord(char)
    index_mod = index % 3
    if index_mod == 0:
        if char_code > 21:
            offset = -21
        else:
            offset = 5
    elif index_mod == 1:
        if char_code > 24:
            offset = -24
        else:
            offset = 2
    else:
        if char_code > 21:
            offset = -20
        else:
            offset = 6
    encrypted += chr(char_code + offset)

print encrypted
```

For fun, it could also be done like this:

```
offsets = [{True: -21, False: 5}, {True: -24, False: 2}, {True: -20, False: 6}]
upper_limits = [21, 24, 21]

plaintext = raw_input("Enter the string ")
encrypted = ''
for index, char in enumerate(plaintext):
    char_code = ord(char)
    index_mod = index % 3
    offset = offsets[index_mod][char_code > upper_limits[index_mod]]
    encrypted += chr(char_code + offset)

print encrypted
```

You could even have

```
offsets = [[5, -21], [2, -24], [6, -20]]
```

but it's less clear what's going on there.

However now that I see the pattern in the offsets (the second always being the first minus 26) that should be done in code:

```
offsets = [5, 2, 6]
upper_limits = [21, 24, 21]

plaintext = raw_input("Enter the string ")
encrypted = ''
for index, char in enumerate(plaintext):
    char_code = ord(char)
    index_mod = index % 3
    offset = offsets[index_mod]
    if char_code > upper_limits[index_mod]:
        offset -= 26
    encrypted += chr(char_code + offset)

print encrypted
```

Comment: Whether or not this is helpful, it isn't an answer to the question.

Comment: Error 'line 21, in <module>encrypted += char(char_code + offset)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable'

Comment: @ShubhamChahal sorry, made a typo (char instead of chr). Fixed.

Comment: @AlexHall try to give input='a'.

Comment: @ShubhamChahal I just did and it gave me `L`. Again, I edited the code.

Comment: @AlexHall yeah it gave `L` but output should be `f`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know what the output was supposed to be. When I run your code in the question though it still gives me `L`. I guess you have some numbers to fix up?

Comment: @ShubhamChahal the problem is probably that you expect `ord` to give the position in the alphabet, when in fact it gives the unicode codepoint (for ASCII characters such as `a`, that's just the position in the ASCII table). For example `ord('a')` is 97 and `ord('A')` is 65. You need to correct for that.

Comment: @AlexHall  for that  `ord('a')%32` or `ord('A')%32` should be used.

Comment: @ShubhamChahal if you say so. I can't tell what the output of the code is supposed to be, so this kind of thing is up to do. I just wanted to show you what good clean code is like.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I'd rather be helpful than do exactly what is expected. This won't hurt anyone.